# Reason for positive enthalpy and volume change of mixing for mixtures showing large positive deviation from Raoult's law

Tags: physical-chemistry

At onset let me make it very clear that similar questions do exist already on this site, but none of them has a kind of answer I expect, hence I ought to ask a fresh question.

It may appear that this question is domain specific (to ChemE) which is not true, I had consulted peers from pure science background they confirmed that it's part of their curriculum too.

As per my understanding

\begin{align}
\Delta H_\mathrm{mix} 
  &= -RT \sum\left(
     \frac{\delta \ln(a_{i})}{\delta \ln(T)}\right)_{P,{x_{i}}}\\
\Delta V_\mathrm{mix} 
  &=\frac{RT}{P} \sum\left(
     \frac{\delta \ln(a_{i})}{\delta \ln(P)}\right)_{T,{x_{i}}}
\end{align}

Literature I am referring to reads

> Positive deviation occurs when the interaction between unlike molecules is weaker than interaction between like molecules.The solutions of this type are characterized by positive Enthalpy of mixing and positive volume of mixing.

I want to know what is the mathematical reasoning as well as intuition behind this statement? How the equations (stated above) predict this behaviour?

**Note:**

*A few comments had asked for derivations of those equations, I had learnt them from an Indian Book on Chemical engineering thermodynamics which may not be know outside my country. A proof for those equations is as follows:*

$$ M = \Sigma x_iM_i° + \Delta M_{(mix)} $$

Where M is any property of solution $x_i$ mole fraction of component i, $M_i°$ molar property of component i, and the $\Delta M_{(mix)}$ property change occurs due to mixing of components in solution. By property of summability of partial molar properties of individual components in solution it is known that $M = \Sigma x_i \bar{M_i}$ where $\bar{M_i}$ is partial molar property of component i.

Rearranging the equation,
$\Delta M = \Sigma x_i (\bar{M_i} - M_i°) $

If M = Gibbs Free Energy

Eqn 1,
$$\Delta G = RT\Sigma x_i ln(a_i)$$
Where $a_i$ is activity of component i in solution,
(*I have jumped the step, you may derive the equation using basic equation for G in terms of fugacity*)

Eqn 2,
$$\bar V_i = (\frac{\delta \bar G_i}{\delta P})_T $$

Eqn 3,
$$(\frac{\delta (G_i°/T)}{\delta T})_P = \frac{-H_i°}{T^2}$$

Equation 2 follows from comparing partial differential equation for G(T,P,${N_i}$)with [fundamental property relation for G](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy)

Equation 3 is from [Gibbs Helmholtz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Helmholtz_equation) Equation

Using equation 1,2 and 3 we can arrive at equations

\begin{align}
\Delta H_\mathrm{mix} 
  &= -RT \sum\left(
     \frac{\delta \ln(a_{i})}{\delta \ln(T)}\right)_{P,{x_{i}}}\\
\Delta V_\mathrm{mix} 
  &=\frac{RT}{P} \sum\left(
     \frac{\delta \ln(a_{i})}{\delta \ln(P)}\right)_{T,{x_{i}}}
\end{align}

*If you are interested in detailed derivation then you may refer "Textbook of Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics" by KV Narayana 2nd Ed pg.no. 308- 310*

Comment: Most of the Internet isn't localised to a single country. So maybe you could still just cite the literature you are quoting. That's just common practice. And Google might actually help you out with that. https://www.google.de/books/edition/Principles_of_Physical_Chemistry/SVBXXwAACAAJ?hl=en

Comment: Which version of the book ( "principles of physical chemistry" by Puri•sharma•pathania) are you quoting? (this is only to check the derivation). My version (46th) has a derivation (Eq 66 in chapter 21, solutions of non-electrolytes) very similar to the one you show, but is not the same.

Comment: @BuckThorn yes we have same edition, in equation 66 using the results from eqn 50 and taking ∆H on one side and rest of stuff on other and then Integration gives that same equation for ∆H,while I didn't went through the derivations from that book as I already had that covered in thermodynamics course for which reference was book that I have mentioned in last line of question, but equations are exactly same, just some rearrangement is needed. Really appreciate your efforts thanks.

Comment: I made an effort to provide a general explanation of what van't Hoff's equation says without dwelling into details of the equations. I also did not address the pressure response, only T response. You want an answer that makes a connection between the equations as derived and their deeper meaning, but the derivation is still not complete and one can see some potential confusing issues. First, when discussing mixing one distinguishes between ideal mixing and excess properties, which refer to changes that cannot be explained by the ideal term. That's what deviations from Raoult's law refer to.

Comment: For ideal mixing, $\Delta H _{mix} = 0$.

Comment: @BuckThorn sorry sir, but I can't agree that your answer is correct one, it isn't wrong but I was asking for different thing, also the equations are for general case you can play with them to use for ideal gases, thanks for taking interest.